# About the adjoint of some differential operator on $L^2(0,1)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

If $T=-d^2/dx^2$ is defined on the domain $D(T)=\{f\in C^2[0,1]: f(1)=f'(0)=f'(1/2)=0\}\subset L^2(0,1)$. What's the Hilbert adjoint operator $T^*$?

Many many thanks for your answers.

Math.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Well, I thought it should be $D(T^*)=\{f\in H^2(0,1): f(1)=f'(0)=0\}$ but in a paper where they treat a similar question , they find $D(T^*)=\{f\in H^2(0,1): f(1)=f'(0)=f'(1/2)=0\}$.

Comment: Any answer guys?